# Express.js middleware that modifies response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I would like to express with middleware functions to modify the response.

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    .. do something ..
    next(); // moves to next middleware
});
```

I can modify the `request` and `response` objects that will be passed on to the following middleware functions. Is there a convention or best-practice to modify these objects?

In my particular case I am setting `res.body` because by using `res.write()` it would actually send already the response payload. Is there some property where I can store the payload and it will be sent later by next middleware functions?

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, I am wondering if there are better ways to do it with express, since the whole purpose of middleware functions is to chain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model your middleware on other middleware that modifies the body, such as Connect's [compress](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/compress.html). You'll see that you need to hook into the response stream, since Express and Connect are dealing with streams not static objects.